# C# Object List Initialization

Tags: c#, list, object, graphql

I have the class below

```cs
public class UserClient
{
    public int client_id { get; set; }

    public Icollection<ClassA> ACollections { get; set; }

    public UserClient()
    {
        ACollections = new Icollection<ClassA>();
    }

    public class ClassA
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Icollection<ClassB> BCollections { get; set; }

        public ClassA()
        {
            BCollections = new Icollection<ClassB>();
        }  

    public class ClassB
    {
        public ClassA ClassA { get; set; }

        public Icollection<ClassC> CCollections { get; set; }

        public ClassB()
        {
            CCollections = new Icollection<ClassC>();
        }

        public class ClassC
        {
            public ClassB ClassB { get; set;}
        }
```

The three classes fetch and store related data from DB using entity framework and graphql and store the data in an object list that appears on the blazor client in the following JSON format

[JSON FORMAT AFTER FETCH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNgk5.jpg)

```
{
    public List<UserClient> allData = new List<UserClient>();
    // Console.WriteLine(results.Data.ClientData.ToList());
                
    allData = results.Data.ClientData.Select(x => new UserClient
    {
        client_id = x.Client_id,
        ClassA    = // <-- this is the point where I Have a problem
    }).ToList();
```

I have  difficulties assinging the contents of the second level, third level objects on the list created.

Comment: Are `ClassA`, `ClassB`, and `ClassC` type **definitions** (not instance members) really nested like that? If not, then please show you **actual** code.

Comment: What I have displayed are navigation properties to help group the objects with a specified relation 0ne - Many --- To be clear and brief, maybe you could help answer how you would initialize the two classes below:  ```

Comment: A "relation" is not a "relationship", and you should not be passing EF entity objects directly into JSON serializers because they can inadvertently load your entire database into memory by infinitely traversing navigation properties. I think your software, as-is, has fundamental design problems elsewhere that you need to address.

Comment: ``` public class UserClient
{
    public int client_id { get; set; }

    public Icollection<ClassA> ACollections { get; set; }

    public UserClient()
    {
        ACollections = new Icollection<ClassA>();
    }

    public class ClassA
    {
        

        public UserClient UserClient { get; set; }  ```

Comment: x.ACollections.First().BCollections ? does this work for you?

Comment: Thank You @AmjadS. I'm happy to inform that is what i needed